# Building python from source

Tags: python, zlib

I'm trying to build python from source including zlib for my user on Red-Hat 6.4.

I created a directory $HOME/soft

Inside that directory I unpacked Python 2.7.8 source and then create a directory where I want python to be installed

```
tar xzf Python-2.7.8.tar.gz 
mkdir python2.7.8
```

Then I configure and install zlib

```
cd Python-2.7.8/Module/zlib
./configure --prefix=/home/myuser/soft
make
make install
```

Then Python

```
cd ../..
./configure --prefix=/home/myuser/python2.7.8
make 
make install
```

I got the following:

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _curses            _curses_panel   
_sqlite3           _ssl               _tkinter        
bsddb185           bz2                dbm             
dl                 gdbm               imageop         
readline           sunaudiodev                        
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


Failed to build these modules:
_multiprocessing   binascii           zlib
```

Some modules could not be installed.
I cannot be root and cannot use sudo.  How to proceed to install those modules ?

Comment: You will have to install the relevant libraries (e.g., readline, bz2, sqlite) in the same way as you installed `zlib`, so that you have the header files for those libraries as well.

Comment: The error regarding `zlib` is different: you'll need to point the compiler to the relevant directories of the zlib header files and library. For example, `CFLAGS=-I/home/myuser/soft/include LDFLAGS=-L/home/myuser/soft/lib ./configure --prefix=/home/myuser/python2.7.8` when configuring Python.

Comment: Thanks, I could install zlib, but the module binascii still doesn't install.  What configuration do I need to install this module ?